# how to integrate zend_dojo in zf application

Tags: zend-framework, dojo

How do you integrate an accordian widget into a helloworld zend project?  This is what I have so far and all I get is the page with the messages no accordians.

Bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initView()
    {
        $view = new Zend_View();
        //$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');

        $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
        $view->addHelperPath('Zend/Dojo/View/Helper/','Zend_Dojo_View_Helper');
        $view->dojo()->addStylesheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');
    }
}
```

Layout File:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>

<html>
<head>

<?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>
<?php echo $this->headMeta() ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink() ?>
<?php echo $this->headStyle() ?>

<?php if ($this->dojo()->isEnabled()){

    $this->dojo()->setLocalPath('/js/dojo/dojo.js')
        ->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');

    echo $this->dojo();
}
?>

<?php echo $this->headScript() ?>

</head>

<body class="tundra">

<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>

<?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

View:

```
<?php // setup required dojo elements:

$this->dojo()->enable()
          ->setDjConfigOption('parseOnLoad', true)

         ->requireModule("dijit.layout.AccordianContainer")
         ->requireModule("dijit.layout.ContentPane")?>   


<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Heeh, this is a content pane">
            Hi!
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="This is as well" selected="true">
            Hi how are you?
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="This too">
            Hi how are you? .....Great, thx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would use "plain" dojo, the time will come where dojo is no longer part of Zend Framework.

Comment: Well by now it's more of the irritation factor. Just have to get it working as it's intended.